# Update ProgressBar from "grandson" backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms

I created WinForms app. in the main UI i created background worker "backgroundworker1" and run some code.
In "backgroundworker1" i created another background worker "SecondBGW" that copy files.
How can I update the UI Progress Bar from the "SecondBGW" background worker?
I know how to update the UI from "backgroundworker1"  (by "ProgressChanged" or "RunWorkerCompleted" events) but not from the "SecondBGW".

```
        public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                }
        
                private void startAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
                    {
                        // Start the asynchronous operation.
                        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                    }
                }
        
                private void cancelAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
                    {
                        // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
                        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                        progressBar1.Value = 0;
                        resultLabel.Text = string.Empty;
        
                    }
                }
        
                private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
                {
                    FirstClass fs = new FirstClass();
                    fs.Go();
                }
        
                private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
                    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                }
        
            }
        
        
        
         internal class FirstClass
            {
                  
                BackgroundWorker SecondBGW = new BackgroundWorker();
                public FirstClass() 
                {
                    SetSecondBGW();
                } 
        
                private void SetSecondBGW()
                {
                    SecondBGW.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                    SecondBGW.ProgressChanged += SecondBGW_ProgressChanged;
                    SecondBGW.DoWork += SecondBGW_DoWork;
                        
                }
        
                public void Go()
                {
        
                    SecondBGW.RunWorkerAsync(); 
                }
        
                private void SecondBGW_DoWork(object? sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                    {
                       
                    }
                    
                    SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();
                    sc.CopyFiles(SecondBGW, e); 
                }
        
                private void SecondBGW_ProgressChanged(object? sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage); 
                }
            }
        
        internal class SecondClass
            {
                public void CopyFiles(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
                {
                    int numOfFiles = 100;
        
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfFiles; i++)
                    {
                        // Copy files
        
                        // How to report to progressBar1 in the UI 
                        worker.ReportProgress(i);
                    }
                }
        
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your code. It's unclear what you mean by "grandson" BackgroundWorker as BGWs simply can't be combined. That's just one of their disadvantages compared to `async/await` and just calling `await Task.Run(()=>MyMethod())`. To upgrade the UI (including any progress bars) you need to handle the `ProgressChanged` event. In all supported .NET Framework and .NET Core versions though, it's simply easier to use `async/await` and possibly the [Progress<T> class](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: `that copy files` what does that code do? It's quite possible there are async variants of the methods it uses. Or it may be possible to copy multiple files concurrently.

Comment: Your `FirstClass` doesn't have a reference to a gui to perform a progress update.  `FirstClass` could expose those events from it's BackgroundWorker.  But it's unclear what your code is doing, because you have one BackgroundWorker just calling another BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with WinForms up until recently, and this is how I always did it:
Firstly, I'd keep track of the `Form1` instance in the `Form1` class:

```cs
public static Form1 Instance;

// constructor
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    Instance = this;
}
```

Then, create a method to be able to access the progress bar:

```cs
public void UpdateProgressBar(int i)
{
    progressBar1.Value = i;
}
```

And finally, in your code in the `SecondClass`, add `Form1.Instance.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Form1.Instance.UpdateProgressBar(i)));` to your `CopyFiles` method like this:

```cs
public void CopyFiles(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int numOfFiles = 100;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfFiles; i++)
    {
        // Copy files

        // How to report to progressBar1 in the UI 
        Form1.Instance.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Form1.Instance.UpdateProgressBar(i)));
        
        worker.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
```

This line of code always confused me a little bit, but basically, you're telling your main thread to call the `UpdateProgressBar()` method when it has time.

This is the final result of the code:
[image: Final product]

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Many thanks it's work greate on the small program that i copy here to demonstrate the problem but when i implement your solution on my big program i get this exception " System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."
I tried to understand the problem but I can't, all the controls are visible before the BGW is created and run the invoke! what I'm missing?

Comment: In that case, I'd need a little bit more code to be able to reproduce the problem

Comment: OK, I solved the problem by moving the "Instance = this" from the Form1() constructor to Form1_Load() function that invoked by the Load event.

Comment: If this answer solved your question, it'd be a good idea to mark it as the accepted one for anyone else that runs into the same problem!